# Solid angles in integral?

Tags: astronomy, definition, thermal-radiation, luminosity

Could somebody explain why we have to integrate over the solid angle when calculating total luminosity in the following:

[image]

The integral over the wavelength makes sense, that a=way we have a total power from the entire spectrum, and multiplying by it's area makes sense, because the Planck function is per area. But why solid angle?

Comment: Not sure but it may come the definition of luminosity which species the angles or aperture of the viewing system.

Answer (score 2):

It's part of the definition of $B_\lambda$. Inherent in the definition of $B_\lambda$ is the treatment of photons as though they are particles that have a position and momentum (in this case, they're a low density of wave packets). I actually find it easier to understand what's going on by considering the phase space density of photons
$$\mathcal{N}_\gamma\left(\vec{x},\vec{p}\right) \equiv \frac{\partial^2N}{\partial x^3 \partial p^3}. \tag1$$

In (1) you naturally have two three dimensional spaces, and $\mathcal{N}_\gamma$ is the number of photons per unit phase space volume. Because you have two 3-dimensional volumes involved, you have two solid angles – one for real space, and one for momentum space. You can work out that this is related to spectral radiance by
$$I_\nu\left(\vec{x},\nu,\hat{k}\right) = hcp^3 \mathcal{N}_\gamma\left(\vec{x},\vec{p}\right),$$
with $\vec{p} = h\nu \hat{k} / c$.

What I like about using $\mathcal{N}_\gamma$ is that

1. the blackbody photon density is given by $\frac{2}{h^3\left[e^{h\nu / kT}-1\right]}$, which is very simple, and
2. $\mathcal{N}_\gamma$ is invariant under the expansion of the universe, making cosmology/GR calculations easier.

So, where does the $\cos\theta$ come from in the solid angle integral in the question? Well, to understand that you need to do a little bit of work. For photons just moving through space, photon number is conserved. So, $\mathcal{N}_\gamma$ participates in a continuity equation with a phase space current density, just like charge density and electric current density, but with more dimensions. The phase space velocity is given by
\begin{align}
   \dot{\vec{x}} & = c \hat{k}\\
   \dot{\vec{p}} & = 0
\end{align}
leading to the phace space current density, $\vec{\mathcal{J}}_\gamma$,
\begin{align}
  \vec{\mathcal{J}}_\gamma\left(\vec{x},\vec{p}\right) = \left[\begin{array}{c}
    c\hat{k} \mathcal{N}_\gamma \\
    0
   \end{array}\right].\tag2
\end{align}

So, to find the rate at which photons are traveling through some surface in phase space you would calculate
$$\int \vec{\mathcal{J}}_\gamma \cdot \hat{n}\,\mathrm{d}A, \tag3$$
where $\hat{n}$ is perpendicular to the surface. The dot product in (3) is where the $\cos\theta$ comes from.

Answer (score 1):

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law) explains, the spectral radiance $B_\lambda$ of a blackbody is the power emitted per unit area of the body, *per unit solid angle of emission*, per unit wavelength. To get the power you have to integrate over the area, the solid angle, and the wavelength.